# Can you put a <c:cout> tag inside the `value` attribute of a <c:set> tag?

Tags: java, jstl

I want to output the value of the xzy variable into the value of the abc variable.

```
<c:set var="abc" value="<c:out value="${xyz}"/>"/>
```

I'm getting an error (`unterminated <c:set> tag`) when I do this.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you must have well-formed markup. `<c:set/>` can have body content instead of a `value` attribute though:

```
<c:set var="abc"><c:out value="${xyz}" /></c:set>
```

I would only use this to take advantage of the XML-escaping provided by `<c:out/>`. Otherwise it's simpler just to set the `value="${xyz}"`.

Comment: This is excellent!. Using this example you can also include values from other .tag files. For example: <c:set var='x'><mytag:other var='s'></c:set>

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
<c:set var="abc" value="${xyz}"/>
```

Remember, **c:out** is basically when you want to write text to the HTML page. In this case you just want to pass the value around, so keep it in variable land.  Think of your java code doing this

```
  String myString = System.out.println("12");
```

That is about what you are doing... :)

Comment: This won't produce the same results; no XML escaping occurs with this method.